# How to save appending model accuracies in a text file?

Tags: python, csv

I am comparing some models and trying output a file with all the model accuracies. However, I have my models in a for loop, and with trying to include a file.write option this only gives the accuracy of the final model. For example my code is this:

```
dataset= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = dataset.drop(["gene"],1)
df = data.iloc[:,0:26]
df = df.fillna(0)
X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_value = le.fit_transform(["certain", "likely", "possible", "unlikely"])
Y = le.fit_transform(data["category"])

sm = SMOTE(random_state=100)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)

seed = 7
logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear',multi_class='auto')
LR_par= {'penalty':['l1'], 'C': [0.5, 1, 5, 10], 'max_iter':[100, 200, 500, 1000]}

rfc =RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
param_grid = {"max_depth": [3],
             "max_features": ["auto"],
              "min_samples_split": [2],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1],
              "bootstrap": [False],
              "criterion": ["entropy", "gini"]}

svm = SVC(gamma="scale")
tuned_parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':(1,0.25,0.5,0.75)}

inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

models = []
models.append(('RFC', GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('LR', GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('SVM', GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))

results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


for name, model in models:
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    output = msg
    file = open("accuracies.txt","w")
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
```

With trying to write the output file, the file 'accuracies.txt' that I create in the for loop only gives the accuracy for SVM, how do I change this to give me the accuracies for each model?

I have also tried:

```
for name, model in models:
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=2, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
    print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_)) #average of all cv folds for a single combination of the parameters you specify 

file = open("accuracies.txt","w")
file.write(results)
file.close()
```

However this gives the error that:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the SVM results are being written because you're overwriting the file in each iteration of the for loop. Try the following:

```py
with open("accuracies.txt","w") as file: # open file before the loop
    for name, model in models:
        nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(nested_cv_results)
        names.append(name)
        msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
        print(msg)
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
        output = msg
        file.write(output) # write output for each iteration
```

For your second attempt, you're trying to write a list object, rather than a string. For this, you can use `f.writelines` rather than `f.write`. Also, be sure to add a new line `\n` if you want items on different lines.

```py
for name, model in models:
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=2, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )\n" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
    print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_)) #average of all cv folds for a single combination of the parameters you specify 

with open("accuracies.txt","w") as file:
    file.writelines(results)
```

Comment: This has worked - thank you so much! Thank you also for the additional answer for my other attempts as well.